# Cable shield connection: ground or earth

Tags: ground, cables, earth, shield

I have an analog sensor which features 3 wires: power supply +, ground (common for supply and signal output) and signal output iself. Sensor is working in industrial environment. I am using shielded cable. Know that only one end should be connected but the question is where - common signal ground or protective earth (PE/mains earth)? The power supply for sensor will be isolated one. I suppose in industrial environment we would like to protect from power equipment capacitively coupled noise assuming that common plane in this type of environment is the mains PE. Does this make any sense?

Comment: You should use 4 internal wires that are shielded. It's called shielded [star-quad cable](https://dt7v1i9vyp3mf.cloudfront.net/styles/news_large/s3/imagelibrary/q/qa_05-3BL2y.njbPmRFrZHnpAm5V1sN1X8Fr9g.jpg). That is the way to transport a signal from a sensor that is powered where one of the sensors connections is also common to signal.

Comment: Yes, but the shield has to be connected somewhere. So what is the best option in industrial environment - PE or common analog signal ground?

Comment: I connect the shield to earth one end only.

Comment: Please link the cable you are planning on using.

Comment: It will be shielded either flat or round ribbon cable for IDC connector. 16 channels in toltal where each output signal has signal ground in the parallel conductor.

Comment: https://uk.farnell.com/3m/3659-37/round-to-flat-cable-37-conductor/dp/1369933?st=ribbon%20cable%20shielded
Most likely this where one conductor is for signal the next one is for ground and so on for 16 channels (EMI things).

Answer (score 1):

The wiring is to be carried out as shown below.

[image]

The shield is to be connected to earth ground, only at the analog input end.